# Walkthrough regarding a do while loop inside of a for loop

Tags: c, do-while

I have a piece of code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int j = 3;
        while (j)
        {
            do
            {
                printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
                j--;
            } while (j == 2);
            printf("Bang\n");
        }
        printf("Pop\n");
    }
}
```

I am a new programming student, and this was one of the pieces of code the professor put on the board to see if we could walk through it. I understand the how this would compile, or so I thought.

Apparently the output for the code an endless loop, but forms a pattern as such:

```
i     j
0     3
0     2
0     1
Bang
0     1
Bang
Pop
1     3
1     2
1     1
Bang
1     1
Bang
Pop
```

The part that is confusing to me is that, the do while loop claims to only do the loop if `while(j ==2)`, yet at no point does the value of `j` seem to matter regarding the output of the loop. I am confused as to why j would go to from 1, before the bang, be subtracted with the `j--;` output Bang, then go back to 1. Also I dont understand why at one point it prints just Bang, but at another points Bang and Pop, i understand its exiting different scopes of loops, but I dont understand why it does that.

I input the code into visual studio 2013 and got a alternative output:

```
i    j
0    3
0    2
bang
0    1
bang pop
1    3
1    2
bang
1    1
```

This makes more sense as printing Bang is adhering to the while(j == 2) loop, yet it still do not know why it prints bang and pop when j gets to 1.

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused as to why j would go to from 1, before the bang, be subtracted with the j--; output Bang, then go back to 1.

You're right when you say that j is 1 before the bang, and being 1 allows it to print "bang". But then it goes back into the while loop, prints 1 again (because it is still 1) goes down to zero (which you don't see because it doesn't print) and then prints "bang" again. Because j is 0 (which you never saw) it gets to exit the while loop and print "pop". The pattern repeats, but now i is 1.

Comment: I still do not understand why it is assumed that once J is 1 it prints bang, when none of the loops indicate that. In addition, how is it that it prints j being 1, yet, as you say, prints bang because j is 1, the print statement for bang is not only after, but outside of the local scope of the i and j print statement.

Comment: I do not understand why j being 1 prompts the program to leave two loops completely when neither of the loops indicate 1 as a parameter for the loop.

Comment: Because 1 != 2, j being equal to 1 is a condition to leave the deepest loop and print bang.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to understand that there is a fundamental difference between `while` and `do-while`.

The former checks the condition *before* entering the loop body so the loop body may execute zero or more times.

The latter checks *after* the loop body so is guaranteed to execute that body at least once. Hence the code snippet:

```
int j = 99;
do {
    puts ("Hello");
while (j == 42);
```

will output `Hello` despite the fact `j` is nowhere *near* `42`.

---

One thing I find very helpful to starters is to actually get a pen and paper and track every single line of code, evaluating it in your head, and keeping records of the current variable values:

```
  i      j    Output
=====  =====  ======
```

This will greatly assist your learning process.

In addition, you can (temporarily) change your `bang/pop` lines to provide more information:

```
printf("Bang %d %d\n", i, j);
printf("Pop %d %d\n", i, j);
```

and this will also make it clearer as to why you're seeing them together.

---

Taking all that information above into account, the reason you're seeing your particular output is because, whenever you exit the inner loop with `j == 0` (having just banged), you also exit the middle loop because `j` being zero is equivalent to `j` being false. That will cause you to pop as well.

This can only happen if `j` *started* the inner loop at `1` - being `do-while`, it will execute at least once and `j` will drop to zero.

The situations where you bang without popping are limited to those situations where you exit the inner loop when `j` is *not* zero.

Has `j` started the inner loop at any other value than `1`, it would have exited at `1` and you would have banged but not popped.

Comment: Yes those were both typos, sorry for the mistakes, I am rushing around trying to get to the bottom of this and overlooked those errors. I understand that with do while it will print the output once despite the conditions, but it doesnt really help explain things for me.

Comment: @Impugnor, then I suggest you follow my advice in the second section of the answer. Sit down with pen and paper and run the code in your wetware.

Comment: @Impugnor, see the update. Honestly, if you want to understand it, you're just going to have to keep slugging away at it, though I hope the update may help out.

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out, the first time around the loop j is 3 and prints automatically adhering to the do while logic, the j-- then kicks in making it 2, the 2 coincides with the while(j == 2) statement, thus loops again printing j being 2. Then after that j-- reduced j to 1 which leaves the loop once, but since j is still a  true value, it coincides with the above while scope which indicates while(j), it leaves to print bang, then goes back to the loop. It prints j being 1 again, then j-- makes the j 0, leaving the loop entirely due to it being a false value.

Comment: @Impugnor, now you're getting it. *See* the machine. *Be* the machine. It will no doubt (once you realise people are mushy and non-logical and computers make much more sense) make you somewhat socially inept as it did me, but I think the benefits outweigh the negatives :-) Just kidding - you can both think like a machine *and* maintain human contact.